# What is the best approach for wrapping an STL container in a custom iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, template-meta-programming

To illustrate, say I have a custom container than makes use of the STL `std::vector` internally. If I typedef `std::vector<char*>::iterator` to `my_container::iterator`, then dereferencing the iterator will return a `char*`. However, my custom container should hide its internals, meaning I want a dereferencing to return a `char`.

How can this be accomplished?

```
class my_container {
public:

    typedef std::vector<char*> vector;

private:

    vector vec_;

};
```

**UPDATE:** `char*` is an example. It does not mean a C string; the example would be clearer with an `int`.

Also, I would like to use `std::forward_iterator_tag` and `std::iterator` as this seems a more standard/current approach.

Comment: You might need to implement your own iterator, one that iterates on two levels (`char*` of the actual iterator, and `char` for your dereference operator).

Comment: Where does `char` come from, do you mean to be iterating over each substring within the vector or just dereferencing twice?

Answer (score 5):

If you want your own iterator, just start writing it as a nested class.  It will need to wrap a `std::vector<char*>::iterator`, intercepting the usual operations (e.g. `++`, `*`, `--`), something like:

```
class iterator
{
  public:
    iterator& operator++() { ++i_; return *this; }
    char& operator*() { return **i_; }
    ...etc...

  private:
    std::vector<char*>::iterator i_;
};
```

If you try it and get stuck, post your attempt and we'll help you further.

Answer (score 4):

The ***best*** way? phew!, tough question.

***one*** way is to use the very useful framework that has been created for exactly this purpose by the nice folks at boost.org:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iterator/doc/

Comment: Yup, this library hits the spot.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boost::indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html).

EDIT: (Untested)

```
struct S
{
    using iterator =
        boost::indirect_iterator<std::vector<char*>::iterator>;
    using const_iterator =
        boost::indirect_iterator<std::vector<char*>::const_iterator>;

    iterator begin() { return iterator(vec_.begin()); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(vec_.begin()); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(vec_.begin()); }
    const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator(vec_.begin()); }
private:
    std::vector<char*> vec_;
};
```

Comment: you could improve your answer explaining how it answer to the question

Comment: What if the wrapped vector is a vector of pairs and I only want to expose the second of each pair?

Comment: is it intentional that the `end()` function return `begin()`?